# Класс Python. Заменить пробел в коде

Tags: python, классы, return, класс

Дан класс:

```
class C:
    ...:
        return 42

c = C()
print(len(c))
```

Что нужно написать вместо `...`, чтобы код вывел `42`?

Answer (score 3):

Ну конечно же нужно описать специальный метод, который отвечает за результат `len`:

```py
def __len__(self):
```